# Magento 2 : How to validate confirm password

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, validation, password

```
Password confirmation not working, code is given below

<div id="password-div" style="display:none">
                                    <div class="field password required">
                                        <label for="password" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password')) ?></span></label>
                                        <div class="control">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                                                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Password')) ?>"
                                                class="input-text"
                                                data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
                                                data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
                                                data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
                                                autocomplete="off" style="width:550px;">
                                            <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
                                                <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                                                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                                                    <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="crm-password-div" style="display:none">    
                                    <div class="field confirmation required">
                                        <label for="password-confirmation" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm Password')) ?></span></label>
                                        <div class="control">
                                            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Confirm Password')) ?>" id="password-confirmation" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true,'validate-customer-password':true, equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off" style="width:550px;">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :-**

```
<div class="field password required" data-mage-init='{"passwordStrengthIndicator": {}}'>
    <label class="label" for="password"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('New Password')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password" id="password"
               data-password-min-length="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getMinimumPasswordLength()) ?>"
               data-password-min-character-sets="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRequiredCharacterClassesNumber()) ?>"
               data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-customer-password':true}"
               autocomplete="off">
        <div id="password-strength-meter-container" data-role="password-strength-meter" aria-live="polite">
            <div id="password-strength-meter" class="password-strength-meter">
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Password Strength')) ?>:
                <span id="password-strength-meter-label" data-role="password-strength-meter-label">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No Password')) ?>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field confirmation required">
    <label class="label" for="password-confirmation"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Confirm New Password')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="password" class="input-text" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirmation" data-validate="{required:true,equalTo:'#password'}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
```